# deploy a desktop java application

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, desktop-application

so i finished a java desktop application. and i'm willing to give it to my client he will be using it on 2 PC's, i used mySql for database.

what's the best way to deploy and host it. i mean i want to use xampp but then how do i fix the IP address of the main host PC so i can use it in xampp configuration.
if i fix it in my pc manually i lose internet, if i use the ipv4 of the PC everything works fine but eventually it will varies and won't stay the same. will it work if i just disable DHCP in the router/modem ?

please if anyone have a good answer i will appreciate it, and excuse me for my lack of knowledge about the whole xampp and networking thingy.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is going to the router settings and setting the Host machine IP to a fixed one.

You don't need to disable the entire DHCP server, just set one machine to use a fixed IP

Otherwise you can implement network discovery on the host machine,
Using something like [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet)